# Writing If condition inside DT datatable options?

Tags: shiny, dt, shinyapps

Apologies for not being able to provide a reproducible example, but below is the options for my datatable. Basically, if the screenshot button is pressed - I don't want the scroll feature enabled - otherwise it should be enabled. Thank you for any help or recommendations! The if statement initially evaluates as false, but the scroll feature is still disabled by default.

Also, does anyone know the meaning of life?

```
 ` options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE, 
                               #pageLength = -1, 
                               if(input$screenshot > 0){
                                 scrollY=NULL
                               } else {
                                 scrollY='50vh'
                               }
                               , scrollCollapse = TRUE`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple. Write your `if` condition outside the DT renderer, inside an observer to a reactive variable. Also, instead of using an action button for **screenshot** I would suggest you to use a [**toggle button**](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/switchInput.html). This would allow you to enable and disable scrolling instead of just disabling it altogether.

```
# You initialize the table with scrolling enabled
react <- reactiveValues(scrollCondition="50vh")

# Toggle button returns TRUE when enabled and FALSE when disabled. So when screenshots are set to TRUE, we make the scrollY property NULL.
observeEvent(input$screenshot,{
       if(input$screenshot==TRUE){
                 react$scrollCondition <- NULL
       }else{
                 react$scrollCondition <- "50vh'"
       }
})


`options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE, 
                               scrollY= react$scrollCondition, 
                               scrollCollapse = TRUE`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works great, thank you for your help! I'd vote up your response if I wasn't a stack overflow newbie.

Comment: @David Happy to help!